# How replace method with a map method? Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some method witch should be replaced with map method. And this is problem for me) Can you help me, please, guys?

This is my method:

```
def groupe_company_files(source_files)
      files = {}
      source_files.each do |file|
        category_name = file.company_files_category.present? file.company_files_category.name : I18n.t('company_files_categories.uncategorized')

        files[category_name] ||= []
        files[category_name] << file
      end
      files
end
```

Comment: This should be probably closed as it has been answered a zillion times: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
def groupe_company_files(source_files)
      files = Hash.new{[]}
      source_files.map{|f| files[f.company_files_category.try(:name) || I18n.t('company_files_categories.uncategorized')] += [f]}
      files  
end
```

Using [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
def groupe_company_files(source_files)
      source_files.inject(Hash.new{[]}){|h,f| h[f.company_files_category.try(:name) || I18n.t('company_files_categories.uncategorized')] += [f];h}
end
```

Using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
def groupe_company_files(source_files)
      source_files.group_by{|f| f.company_files_category.try(:name) || I18n.t('company_files_categories.uncategorized')}
end
```

Comment: Thank you very mach! It's very helpful!